# iPad css positioning - Can you test this on an iPad for me, please

Tags: css, ipad, positioning

I'm having a problem with CSS positioning for the iPad. It looks fine in the iPad Simulator from apple but when I go to the store and look at it on an actual iPad the video player is still being pushed far down the page.

The problem is that the project is due in an hour and I don't have the time to go back to the store and check it out. Could anyone look at this on their iPad and let me know if the video is at least near the top of the screen instead of being pushed down? I would really appreciate it.

Here's the link:

http://davidarabis.com/HolidayCard05/

Thanks

Comment: Correctness is very subjective, please post a screenshot of what you are expecting approximately.

Comment: How does somebody who does not own an iPad get hired to design a mission critical site for the iPad?

Comment: your site background image is beautiful

Comment: Thank you Hira, really I just need to know if the video is centered and close to the top. If it is, then what I'm doing is correct.

Comment: Why is `<video></video>` contained inside `<object></object>`?  Maybe that's your whole problem.

Comment: This question will not benefit anyone but the OP. Downvoted

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem on my iPod Touch too.

Why did you put your `<video>` tags *inside* your `<object>` tags?  Maybe that's a problem.

I suspect it's being pushed down in iOS by the unseen/unsupported Flash content above.  You also have a `</embed>` closing tag where one is not required.

What if you put `<video>` outside and *before* `<object>`?

```
<video class="noFlash" src=video/FB_HolidayCard_Movie.mov controls width="626" height="470" poster="images/envelope.gif">
    <!--Download video:<a href="video/FB_HolidayCard_Movie.mov">mov</a>-->
</video>

<object class="objectT" data="video/FB_HolidayCard.swf?video=file.flv" width="770" height="500">
    <param name="movie" value="video/FB_HolidayCard.swf?video=file.flv">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed src="video/FB_HolidayCard.swf?video=file.flv" width="770" height="500" wmode="transparent"/>
</object>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#video

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video

Comment: The way it's supposed to work is if you have Flash it will play Flash but for the iPad which doesn't support flash HTML5 video will play.

Comment: @xoam, yes, the desired effect is obvious.  It's your implementation that I question.